# Laravel - Chunk update too slow (SQLSRV - MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, laravel, performance, chunking

I have a function in controller that selects the entire table Clients of a SQL Server database (remote, with less than 1 ms connection), and updates the Clients table in my MySQL DB, there are approx. 15000 rows.
When it was on development in my computer (Windows 10), used to take 24-26 seconds to complete the update. Now in the production server, it takes between 8 and 10 minutes. I tested the connection between my server and the SQL Server and is really fast, so the problem is not the SQL driver but MySQL.

Server: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, CPU usage2.13% of 4 CPU(s), Memory usage 79.13% (6.26 GiB of 7.91 GiB)
MySQL Ver 5.7.32
Mytop: 50 qps (now) when running the fuction,  Slow qps: 0.0, Key efficiency 50% (it was 97% before restarting MYSQL service)

Code

```
ClienteAsesorSql::where('Concepto', 'NOT LIKE', '%RESERVADO%')
            ->chunk(500, function ($clientes_asesor) {
                foreach ($clientes_asesor as $clientes) {
                    $cliente_opyme = Cliente::updateOrCreate(['cli_id' => $clientes->ClienteId],[
                        'cli_id' => $clientes->ClienteId,
                        'cli_nombre' => $clientes->Concepto,
                        'cli_email' => $clientes['e-mail'],
                        'cli_telefono' => $clientes->Telefono,
                        'cli_movil' => $clientes->SMS,
                        'cli_domicilio' => $clientes->DomicilioNoFiscal,
                        'created_at' => $clientes->FechaEstado
                    ]);
                $cliente_opyme ->save();
                }
            });
```

Comment: I would suggest monitoring the executed queries with for example the laravel debug bar.

Comment: Or neor profiler

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) STATUS; 
H) MYTOP  report 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck sorry for the late response, here are the links

MYSQL TUNER https://pastebin.com/Z3tdBTqN
GLOBAL VARIABLES https://pastebin.com/Q8eXtMYM
GLOBAL STATUS https://pastebin.com/C9RsE2NR
FULL PROCESS LIST https://pastebin.com/TcifGDsz
INNODB STATUS https://pastebin.com/FQy8gWKe
MYTOP https://pastebin.com/tWrakKMe

Comment: Thank you, will work on your analysis tomorrow (if the creek does not rise too much).

Comment: Please post TEXT of your query used to update rows in the MySQL table clientes; also, is your data on rotating, SSD or NVME storage devices?  Could you post on pastebin.com text results of iostat -xm 5 3;  and we will complete your workload analysis.  What is the maximum lag time allowed to get your MySQL table matched to your controller?  Days, Hours, Minutes or Seconds allowed?

Comment: @pmpato Please post the additional information requested on Dec 23 at 12:31 so we can complete your analysis.  Happy New Year. :)